# Grunt registerTask() Not Running Tasks in List

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, rendr

I have added the following [`registerTask`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registertask) calls to this [`Gruntfile.js`](https://github.com/airbnb/rendr/blob/master/examples/06_appview/Gruntfile.js)

```javascript
grunt.task.registerTask('runDebug', 'Run the app with debug flag', function() {
  var done = this.async();
  grunt.util.spawn({
      cmd: 'node',
      args: ['--debug', './node_modules/nodemon/nodemon.js', 'index.js'],
      opts: {
        stdio: 'inherit'
      }
    }, function (error, result, code) {
      if (error) {
          grunt.log.write (result);
          grunt.fail.fatal(error);
      }
      done();
    });
  grunt.log.writeln ('node started');
  grunt.util.spawn({
      cmd: 'node-inspector',
      args: ['&'],
      opts: {
          //cwd: current working directory
      }
    },
    function (error, result, code) {
      if (error) {
        grunt.log.write (result);
        grunt.fail.fatal(error);
      }
      done();
    });
  grunt.log.writeln ('inspector started');
});

grunt.task.registerTask('debug', ['runDebug', 'compile', 'watch']);
```

The new `debug` task is similar to the existing `server` task.  However, `grunt server` command runs `compile`, `watch`, and `runNode` tasks, whereas `grunt debug` command only runs `runDebug` task.

What am I missing here?  Why aren't the `compile` and `watch` tasks run with `grunt debug` command.

Comment: where are the other task?

Comment: Click the Gruntfile.js link above or [here](https://github.com/airbnb/rendr/blob/master/examples/06_appview/Gruntfile.js)

Comment: Is the `debug` task registered after the `compile` task is registered?

Comment: Yes, right after the `server` task.  Similarly, `runDebug` is placed right after `runNode` task.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is calling the `done()` function returned by `this.async()` more than once. This could be confusing Grunt. I would suggest calling a function of your own which could named `spawned()` instead of calling `done()` directly in your callbacks. The function could be something like:

```
var expected_spawns = 2;
function spawned() {
    if (!--expected_spawns)
        done();

    if (expected_spawns < 0)
        throw new Error("too many spawns!") // Or some of Grunt's fail functions.
}
```

This way `done()` will be called once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Louis.  Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem.

Comment: Fair enough. There may be something else interfering right now (which I can't see) but calling done more than once from the same task does confuse Grunt.